# How to remove the extra / before URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js, stripe-payments, netlify-function

I'm using Netlify Functions, Stripe API, NUXT and Axios for my project.

On my site I make an Axios post request, using this method:

```
async checkout() {
  try {
    const response = await this.$axios.$post(
      "/.netlify/functions/payment_cart",
      {
        cart: this.shoppingCart,
      }
    );
    window.location.href = response.stripe.url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
},
```

Inside the payment_cart function I create a Stripe session, providing a success_url:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
   line_items: line_items,
   shipping_options: shipping_array,
   allow_promotion_codes: true,
   mode: "payment",
   success_url:
     process.env.BASE_URL + "/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
   cancel_url: process.env.BASE_URL + "/cancel",
});
```

When the payment is completed, it should forward to the success_url, where {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is replaced with an actual value.

So far everything's good. The function works and the payment's registered.

Stripe DOES return the correct URL, I've tested this using `console.log(success_url)`. But somehow, the browser adds an extra slash before the parameters, making it impossible for Nuxt to read the parameters.

*notice the / before the ? in the output*

```
https://mywebsite.com/success/?session_id=123456789
```

The ugly way to fix this is to rewrite the URL using something like

```
this.$route.fullPath.replace(
    "/success/?session_id=",
    "/success?session_id="
  )
```

but this way I cannot use any other parameters combined with `session_id` so this is not the solution.

Localhost this problem doesn't occur at all. Modifying the success_url by hardcoding the BASE_URL env doesn't work either.

What do I need to alter to prevent this extra /?

Comment: This is a trailingSlash "issue" as answered à few times here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+trailingSlash I'm not sure how it is an issue tho because it should work fine in that way. Depending on which setting you want to go, check the answer + doc to fully understand the consequences of such. Otherwise, feel free to make a small replace, no huge harm with that approach.

Comment: @kissu but does this also count for adjustment mid-string? The slash is not inserted between the env and string, it is inserted in the middle of the string.

Comment: Isn't `session_id` your query param here? All good if so, valid URL.

Comment: Yes it is. Still, localhost doesn't add this slash and then everything works just fine, Chrome adds the slash and the code breaks.

Comment: Not sure why that one breaks, should be fine since it's valid. Maybe Stripe wants a really specific URL or maybe you could allow it somehow? As of why it's doing that, it's written in my past answers (configuration of the server you're hosting on mainly).

Comment: The problem isn't Stripe. It returns the right URL. Also, inside the callback function it processes the right URL. Just when back on the page, than the URL is altered.